# Recursion on Prolog

Tags: recursion, prolog, successor-arithmetics

I'm trying to write a Prolog recursion that will return the following representation for numbers:

1 --> s(0)

2 --> s(s(0))

3 --> s(s(s(0)))
...

I used the following code:

```
retnum(s(0),1). %Stop Condition
retnum(S,Z):-
    retnum(s(S),Z1),
    Z is Z1+1.
```

but when I try to run prediction :

```
retnum(A,2).
```

I get result A=0, and if I continue I get error with stuck limit exceeded.
I was expecting to get a result A = s(s(0)).
I tried also to add additional stop condition : retnum(0,0).

Any idea where is my mistake and if there is better way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the recursive call incorrectly. The argument to the recursive instance should be smaller than the original (more generally: converging to a boundary condition).
This might give you what you want:

```
retnum(s(0), 1).
retnum(s(S), Z) :-
    retnum(S, Z1),
    Z is Z1 + 1.
```

But this is even better.

```
retnum1(s(0), 1).
retnum1(s(S), Z) :-
    Z > 1, Z1 is Z - 1,
    retnum1(S, Z1).
```

Try to `trace/0` and see why it is so.

Comment: This now gets the right answer for `retnum(A,2)`  but will still loop thereafter.

Comment: @false: are you suggesting another way of writing `retnum` other than `retnum1` ?

Comment: I think he is talking about something like `retnum1(s(0), 1) :- !.` to prevent a choice point there? I don't know if this is "good" or "bad" practice, I am also still quite new to Prolog.

Comment: @rajashekar: Either do it manually (with lots of error-prone `var/1` tests and such) or use `library(clpfd)`.

Comment: @MarkusWeninger: Your suggestion `retnum1(s(0), 1) :- !.` would make the answers to `retnum1(X, N)` incomplete. `retnum1(X, N), N = 2` would now fail incorrectly.

Answer (score 2):

As recommended by @false, the best approach is to use [`library(clpfd)`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=summary-lib-clpfd). However, if you don't want to use that library, a possible solution is to consider two different cases:

- **deterministic case** [*natural N to be converted into  Peano's form is a constant*]: starting from *N*, recursively decrement this value, until reach value 0 (a unique solution can be generated).
- **non-deterministic case** [*natural N to be converted into Peano's form is a variable*]: starting from 0, recursivelly increment this value, producing a new natural *N* at each step (infinitely many solutions can be generated).

```
% nat(?Natural, ?Peano)

  nat(N, P) :-
     (  integer(N) -> nat_det(N, P)
     ;  var(N)     -> nat_nondet(N, P)).

  nat_det(0, 0) :- !.
  nat_det(N, s(P)) :-
     succ(M, N),
     nat_det(M, P).

  nat_nondet(0, 0).
  nat_nondet(N, s(P)) :-
     nat_nondet(M, P),
     succ(M, N).
```

Here are some examples:

```
?- nat(2, P).
P = s(s(0)).

?- nat(2, s(s(0))).
true.

?- nat(2, s(s(s(0)))).
false.

?- nat(N, s(s(s(0)))).
N = 3.

?- N = 4, nat(N, P).
N = 4,
P = s(s(s(s(0)))).

?- nat(N, P), N = 4, !. % we know that there exist only one solution!
N = 4,
P = s(s(s(s(0)))).

?- nat(N, P).
N = P, P = 0 ;
N = 1,
P = s(0) ;
N = 2,
P = s(s(0)) ;
N = 3,
P = s(s(s(0))) ;
...
```

Comment: Bonus: This version fails for `nat(1+0,X)`

Comment: Yes, I only considered the cases where X is a constant number or a variable. Anyway, it's possible to extend the definition to handle numeric expressions as well.

Comment: Fine as is! There are many other definitions that fail for `0+0` yet succeed for `1+0`